# Test output folder not created in target/surefire reports when I run as maven Test

Tags: selenium-rc

Test output folder not created in target/surefire reports when I run as maven Test.
When i run my suite as maven test, surefire reports gets updated but test-output folder is not created. But when I run as Testng Suite, test-output folder is created.

what should I do to have test-output folder created on Run->Maven test?

Answer (score 1):

When you run as Testng Suite you would be using Testng's default report location which is

```
${your base dir}/test-output
```

When you are running from maven, you are basically using Maven's surefire plugin to execute the testng tests.  The reports output directory by default for surefire is

```
${your build directory}/surefire-reports
```

That is why you see the discrepancy in both runs.
To get the output in the same folder as testng does, you can explicitly specify the reports directory for the surefire plugin under the configuration section

```
<reportsDirectory>${basedir}/test-output</reportsDirectory>
```

and then run as maven-test to see the output there.

You can refer to the below link to see how to configure your pom's surefire plugin.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: No, I am still not able to get TestNG Reports and Maven reports simultaneously when I run as Run->Maven test

Comment: I think your question was  "what should I do to have test-output folder created on Run->Maven test?" :)  So that was the answer to that.
Can you paste your surefire plugin configuration.  I suspect you have kept usedefaultlisteners property as false.

Comment: After including <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> in my configuration file, now i am able to view TestNG Reports as well as Surefire Reports. But now, if I want to edit the name of Suite folder, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
               <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```